# Replace underscore with slash in the URL and cut the extension

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I have a file, http://example.com/house_location.phtml. I need to call the URL string http://example.com/house/location (without the ending slash) and that URL must execute house_location.phtml.

So I need to replace "_" with "/" and cut the extension ".pthml".

My last try was:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+house_([^/]+)\.phtml
RewriteRule ^ /house/%1? [L,R]
RewriteRule ^house/([^/]+)$ /house_$1.phtml [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.phtml [NC,L]
```

But it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how the rewrite rule should look like

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$ $1_$2.phtml
```

(Written on mobile phone)

Comment: What not use `.+` instead of `[a-z]+` in case there will be numbers in the query?

Comment: Then add the numbers too. As a programmer you know what you expect in data. If you use .+ even //// would be matched